# Identifying third-law pairs in two masses connected by a string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Consider two masses connected by a string over a pulley, like so:

[image]

Where mass $M$ is held in place by a hand.

I'm asked to draw free-body diagrams for mass $m$ and $M$ individually, and identify third-law pairs in the two diagrams. I'm then asked to consider when the hand moves and mass $m$ begins accelerating downwards.

We can assume the surface to be frictionless and the pulley to be massless.

It doesn't seem to me that there are *any* third-law pairs. The only third-law pairs I can identify in the diagram are the normal forces between the hand and the block (in the first case).

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: yes, you are wrong, cant you think of any other forces acting on each mass?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny In what way? Third-law pairs must a) act on two objects and b) be of the same type and magnitude. I see no such pairs here?

Comment: each force you can identify will have a pair. Can you find any other forces other than the ones between the hand and the mass on the table?

Comment: Mass $m$ will have two forces, the tension $T$ of the rope, and the force of gravity $F_g$. Mass $M$ will have the normal force from the hand, $F_g$ and the normal force between the surface and the mass, and $T$ the tension.

Comment: good!!! now find the reaction (pair) of each one, which is the force that the masses do to the objects that make a force on them

Comment: Let's see. It cannot be $F_g$, gravity, or the normal force from the surface. We're not diagramming the hand, so it can't be the normal forces between the hand and mass $M$. That only leaves... tensional forces $T$?

Comment: you have already found at least 2 pairs, $m$ 'pulls' on the rope: the rope 'pulls on $m$. And, $M$ 'pushes' the surface: the surface 'pushes' back.

Comment: the reaction will not be on M. For instance, the reaction to the hand is a force from the mass on the hand, the reaction to earth's gravity is the gravitational force that the mass does on earth, the reaction to the tension is the force the mass does to the string, etc

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't seem to me that there are any third-law pairs.

Every force has its third law pair, but indeed you are correct that none of the forces acting on m form a third law pair with any of the forces acting on M.

For M there are four forces: weight, tension, contact force from the ground and the contact force from the hand. The third law pairs act on the earth, the string, the ground, and the hand respectively. None of them act on m.

Similarly for m there are two forces: weight and tension. The third law pairs of those forces act on the earth and the string respectively. None of them act on M